# exact matching between two strings - linear edit distance?

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is the problem, given a string with characters from: `a-z`, `.`, `*`, and another string with characters from `a-z`. where `*` can delete the character before it, otherwise * is skipped and `.` can match any single character. the question is whether the first string can match the second one.

**Note:** That is the statement of the problem as I found, but in this case the character `*` performs the same function that `?` in a regular expression.

Example:

```
isMatch("a*", "") = true; //"a*" could be "a" or an empty string ""
isMatch(".", "") = false; 
isMatch("ab*", "a") = true; 
isMatch("a.", "ab") = true; 
isMatch("a", "a") = true;
```

I've already solved this problem using a slightly modified edit distance, which I only know a 2D dynamic programming approach. I wonder whether exists a linear solution for this problem, maybe it is solvable without a dp approach?

Comment: Does the * match multiple copies?  For example, what is `isMatch("aaaaaa", "a*")`?

Comment: no, * only can delete the character before it. The second string only contains characters from a-z, so it should be isMatch("a*","aaaaaa") and the answer is false, because as I said in the example above "a*" could be "a" (in this case * is omitted) or "" (* deleted the character a). I forgot to mention that * only appears after a character from a-z or '.', so is not possible to have something like this "a**" or `"*a*"`.

Comment: Okay... so * is akin to the ? operator in a regular expression?

Comment: i wouldn't change the meaning of any regex meta character. `*` means zero or more times, why change the meaning. if someone else works with you on your projet, they will have to learn a new syntax (as easy as it may be), yet it is still regex. just a thought

Comment: Yes, my bad. I just wrote it as equal as I found the problem.

Comment: @gwillie yeah. Here * is just the same meaning with {0,1} in the regex.

Comment: I think DP is good approach. With backtracking implementation and stopping when there is no solution (test by length or first character to match), I think it is O(n*number_of_asterisks). Which in worst case is O(n^2), but I think even in cases with lot of asterisks backtracking will find first solution fast.

Comment: Consider asking CS-related questions on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @RealzSlaw for the advice. My question was looking for a linear solution and it seems to be impossible, simply because of this case(now with regex syntax):

```
isMatch("a?a?b?b?b?a?a?b?a?","abbab")
```

It asks whether `abbab` is a subsequence of `aabbbaaba` and It's a NP-hard as far as I know, so linear solution seems to be infeasible.